# $a == $b или preg_match("/^$a/", $b) - что выбрать и почему?

Tags: php

Вариант 1:

```
if (
$a == $b &&
$a == $c &&
$a == $e
)
```

Вариант 2:

```
if (
preg_match("/^$a/", $b) &&
preg_match("/^$a/", $c) &&
preg_match("/^$a/", $e)
)
```

Какой из вариантов выбрать и почему?

P.S. Предполагаю, что первый вариант выполняется быстрее, но все же, хочется услышать мнения пользователей, которые действительно знают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preg_match навряд ли быстрее обычного сравнения, так как ему нужно как минимум подгружать парсер регулятор. А сравнение вызовет себе [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) и все делов.
Но вот что будет, если в $a окажется регулярное выражение...

Answer (score 0):

При первом варианте проверяется равенство, а при втором вхождение.
1 ) 1 = 1fghfgh : true 
2 ) 1sdfsdf3 = 1 : false, т.к. не входит в подстроку

```
$a = "1ertert";
$b = 1;
if ($a == $b )
    echo "true<br/>";
else
    echo "false<br/>";

if (preg_match("/^$a/", $b))
    echo "true<br/>";
else
    echo "false<br/>";
```

Comment: Т.е. вариант с равенствами подходит только для числовых выражений, а для обычного текста? Например, для html кода страницы?

Comment: <pre><code>
<?php
$a = "a";
$b = "a";
if ($a == $b )
 echo "true<br/>";
else
 echo "false<br/>";
?>
</code></pre>
<pre><code>
<?php
$a = "a";
$b = "b";
if ($a == $b )
 echo "true<br/>";
else
 echo "false<br/>";
?>
</code></pre>

Что мешает проверить?

Answer (score 0):

Я-бы посоветовал так:

```
if ( $a === $b === $c === $e )
```

`===` - это строгое сравнение, без приведения типов